# Disable and enable ext4 journaling ?

Tags: ubuntu, ext4, journaling

If I disable the journaling function of an EXT4-filesystem using the command `tune2fs -O ^has_journal /dev/sda` and enable it after the next start, will the data saved on the harddisk remain unaffected or are they lost ? 
(Ubuntu 16.04 LTS)

Comment: Journals are meta-data; are you planning on an orderly reboot (close files, unmount filesystem), or some sort of interrupted-write testing?

Comment: In fact I am trying to spin down my Western Digital harddisks with the program 'hd-idle', which tells me that there still are some read/write access, just a few Kilobytes per minute. But with atop, iotop, htop, iostat etc. I haven't been able to detect the cause. So I thought about disabling the journal, but quite probably I am going to enable it again after the short test. 
(root device is a ssd, sda and sdb belong to raid1_a, sdc and sdb to raid1_b and raid_a and raid_b form one volume group).

Comment: Does `hd-idle` still show unexplained read and write accesses when your disk is plugged in but unmounted?

Comment: Yes, it indeed shows r/w-accesses when it is unmounted, so it doesn't look like a journaling issue, but I am running out of ideas what else could be the cause. I also can hear a 'click' sound every ca. 20 seconds, which I can't hear when I am just in the BIOS. 
smartctl (long test) doesn't show anything special.

Comment: Typical output is:

`root@ubuntu:~# hd-idle -i 0 -a sda -i 300 -a sdb -i 300 -a sdc -i 300 -a sdd -i                     300 -d`
`probing sda: reads: 183794, writes: 242`

`probing sdb: reads: 163945, writes: 242`

`probing sdc: reads: 146075, writes: 80`

`probing sdd: reads: 144003, writes: 80`

`probing sda: reads: 183794, writes: 242`

`probing sdb: reads: 163945, writes: 242`

`probing sdc: reads: 146075, writes: 80`

`probing sdd: reads: 144003, writes: 80`

`probing sda: reads: 183794, writes: 242`

`probing sdb: reads: 163945, writes: 242`

`probing sdc: rea...`

Comment: Nowaday `idle3-tools` are availabe per default in Ubuntu, but actually aren't working. Not from the official Ubuntu-repo neither from the normal homepage. I found a working version of `wd5746_64`, telling me that my harddisks (WD 5 TB Red and WD 8 TB Red) can not be updated. The Intellipark problem seems to be eliminated.

Answer (score 1):

As already told tools like `atop`, `iotop`, `htop`, `iostat` haven't been were helpful. 
`blktrace -d /dev/sda -o - | blkparse -i -` showed me that `parted`, `smartctl` and one other process (`udevd` ?) accessed the disc. 
Strangely enough no config-file had smartctl enabled.... 
[auditd](https://serverfault.com/questions/93783/make-a-hard-disk-sleep-and-only-wake-up-when-needed/834902#834902) finally helped me to track down the troublemaker, revealing the correlation between the start of smartctl and `webmin`. `webmin` checks periodically the temperature of the harddisks, this option can be disabled in `Webmin --> Webmin --> Configuration --> Background Status Collection`. One should also disable the options `Collect system status in background` and `Collect available package updates`.